# Displaying items in columns (Rails)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a rails app. I've got a bunch of 'lesson' objects that I'm looping through, and I'd like to have them in 3 three different columns. There are 21 objects total, so 7 in each column.

```
<% lessons.each do |lesson| %>

    <% status = user.lesson_user_status.where(lesson: lesson)[0].status %>

    <% if status != "completed" && lesson.title != "Pre/Post Quiz"%>
        <% if(!hasSeenAvailableLesson) %>
            <%= link_to lesson.title, show_lesson_path(lesson), class: "btn btn-default #{status}", "data-toggle"=> "tooltip", title: lesson.description %>
            <% hasSeenAvailableLesson = true %> 
        <% else %>
            <%= link_to lesson.title, '', class: "btn btn-default blocked #{status}", "data-toggle"=> "tooltip", title: lesson.description %>
        <% end %>

        <br>
        <br>
    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

I think using the Bootstrap columns would be a good idea, but I don't know how to implement it here. How can I tell the program to have 7 lessons in each column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check this idea!**

And modify as you wish.

[Bootstrap grid examples](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)

```
<div class="col-md-12"> #(12 / 4 = 3 (for columns you want))
<% ctr = 0 %>

# iteration starts here
<% lessons.each do |lesson| %>

  <% if ctr == 0 || ctr == 3 %>
    # new column to make
    <div class="col-md-4">
    # insert data here
    ....
    # return ctr to 0 (for checking another count)
    <% if ctr == 3 %>
      <% ctr = 0 %>
    <% end %>
    # or <% if ctr == 3 then ctr = 0 %>  
  <% else %>
    # insert data ONLY (DON'T CREATE NEW COLUMN)
    .....
    # closing of <div>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <% ctr += 1%>
<% end %>
# iteration ends here
</div>
```